# Drawing colored US State map with cut_number() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe called "drawdata":

```
GeoName Ranking
1   Alabama 15
2   Alaska  2
3   Arizona 28
4   Arkansas    12
5   California  19
6   Colorado    7
7   Connecticut 42
8   Delaware    37
9   District of Columbia    9
10  Florida 38
11  Georgia 11
12  Hawaii  48
13  Idaho   10
14  Illinois    16
15  Indiana 26
16  Iowa    34
17  Kansas  27
18  Kentucky    20
19  Louisiana   4
20  Maine   51
21  Maryland    30
22  Massachusetts   39
23  Michigan    14
24  Minnesota   23
25  Mississippi 41
26  Missouri    32
27  Montana 25
28  Nebraska    21
29  Nevada  45
30  New Hampshire   47
31  New Jersey  33
32  New Mexico  5
33  New York    44
34  North Carolina  13
35  North Dakota    31
36  Ohio    35
37  Oklahoma    6
38  Oregon  18
39  Pennsylvania    40
40  Rhode Island    49
41  South Carolina  29
42  South Dakota    46
43  Tennessee   43
44  Texas   3
45  Utah    17
46  Vermont 50
47  Virginia    8
48  Washington  24
49  West Virginia   22
50  Wisconsin   36
51  Wyoming 1
```

And I want to draw a US State map with different colors for each ranking. The code I have is:

```
  names(drawdata) = c('region','value')
  drawdata[,1] = tolower(drawdata[,1])
  states = data.frame(state.center, state.abb)
  states_map = map_data("state")
  df = merge(drawdata, states_map, by = "region")
  df$num = 49
  p1 = ggplot(data = df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group))
  p1 = p1 + geom_polygon(aes(fill = cut_number(value, num[1])))
  p1 = p1 + geom_path(colour = 'gray', linestyle = 2)
  p1 = p1 + scale_fill_brewer('', palette = 'PuRd')
  p1 = p1 + coord_map()
  p1 = p1 + scale_x_continuous(breaks=NULL) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=NULL)
  p1 = p1 + theme(legend.position="none")
  p1 = p1 + geom_text(data = states, aes(x = x, y = y, label = state.abb, group = NULL), size = 2)
  p1
```

This perfectly works if 'num', or the number of colors to fill, is small. However, when I set 'num=49', then it produces an error:

```
Error in cut.default(x, breaks(x, "n", n), include.lowest = TRUE, ...) : 
  'breaks' are not unique
```

When I alter the code from

```
p1 = p1 + geom_polygon(aes(fill = cut_number(value, num[1])))
```

to

```
p1 = p1 + geom_polygon(aes(fill = cut_number(unique(value), num[1])))
```

then it gives me a different error:

```
Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:cut_number(unique(value), num[1])
```

I want a map where every 49 States in the map have different colors, each reflecting their 'Ranking'. Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brewer palettes deliberately have small maximums (generally < 12) since it's pretty much impossible for humans to map the subtle differences to the discrete values you have. You *can* achieve what you're looking for by "faking" it with `scale_fill_gradient2` (NOTE: I deliberately left the legend in as you should too):

```
library(ggplot2)

names(drawdata) <- c('region','value')
drawdata[,1] <-  tolower(drawdata[,1])

states <- data.frame(state.center, state.abb)
states <- states[!(states$state.abb %in% c("AK", "HI")),] # they aren't part of states_map

states_map <- map_data("state")

p1 <- ggplot()
# borders
p1 <- p1 + geom_map(data=states_map, map=states_map,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=region),
                    color="white", size=0.15)
# fills
p1 <- p1 + geom_map(data=drawdata, map=states_map,
                    aes(fill=value, map_id=region),
                    color="white", size=0.15)
# labels
p1 <- p1 + geom_text(data=states, 
                     aes(x=x, y=y, label=state.abb, group=NULL), size=2)
# decent projection
p1 <- p1 + coord_map("albers", lat0=39, lat1=45)
p1 <- p1 + scale_fill_gradient2(low="#f7f4f9", mid="#df65b0", high="#67001f")
# better theme
p1 <- p1 + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)
p1 <- p1 + theme_bw()
p1 <- p1 + theme(panel.grid=element_blank())
p1 <- p1 + theme(panel.border=element_blank())
p1 <- p1 + theme(axis.ticks=element_blank())
p1 <- p1 + theme(axis.text=element_blank())
p1
```

[image]

You can get an even better result with `scale_fill_distiller` which does alot under the scenes to let you use a Color Brewer palette with continuous data (I'd argue you do not have continuous data tho):

```
p1 <- p1 + scale_fill_distiller(palette="PuRd")
```

[image]

I'd strongly suggest continuing to use `cut` like you had originally and having a max of 9 breaks to fit into the Color Brewer palette you're trying to work with. In reality, folks are still going to need a table to really grok the rankings (never assume Americans know either state shapes, locations or even the two-letter abbreviations for them), so I'd also pretty much just suggest using an actual table with full names at least with this choropleth if not in place of it.

Note also that the way you're trying to build the map deliberately excluded Alaska, Hawaii and the District of Columbia. You'll need to use a real shapefile and something like I cover [here](https://rud.is/b/2014/11/16/moving-the-earth-well-alaska-hawaii-with-r/) to get them to show up nicely.

Answer (score 1):

If you want different colors for each state, using a gradient, you can work with `scale_fill_gradient`.  Here is one version, using green and red at the ends of the gradient, so that each state is on that scale.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = value)) +
  geom_path(colour = 'gray', linestyle = 2) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red") +
  coord_map() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=NULL) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=NULL) +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  geom_text(data = states, aes(x = x, y = y, label = state.abb, group = NULL), size = 2)
```

[image]